# what is the precision difference between a double and a very long integer?

Tags: c++, precision, integer-overflow, double-precision

Take

```
 36103009879073133562313702394913733
 36103009879073133562313702394913733.0
```

as an example,

What is the difference in precision when representing a very long integer into double in C++?

Comment: In future, please tag questions with the relevant programming language.

Comment: thank you! I cannot create tag myself due to low reputation

Comment: You don't need to create a tag, you simply need to use the correct tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there is no `very long` type in C++. I assume you are talking about a 64-bit integer type and that `double` corresponds to the 64-bit IEE 754 floating point representation.

A 64 bit integer has (up to) 64 bits of precision; i.e. roughly 19 decimal digits (assuming an unsigned integer type).  By contrast, a 64 bit IEE floating point has 52 bits of precision; i.e. roughly 15 decimal digits.

The example you give has 35 decimal digits, which means that it can't be represented as a 64 bit integer *at all*.  The `double` representation of that number would lose roughly the last 20 decimal digits of precision.

Reference:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: thank you! I am trying to handle a nonlinear system with such very long integer parameters as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255722/precision-loss-when-solving-nonlinear-equations-with-long-integer-parameters-by, do you think factoring all such integers into prime factors OK?

Comment: I don't see how it would help.